# Спарсить данные с сайта js, vuejs

Tags: javascript, json, xml, vue.js

Здравствуйте друзья, только начал изучение js, не могу понять как извлечь данные отсюда https://swapi.co/api/people/ Это нужно сделать с помощью обычного js или vuejs

Нужно вытащить все `name` в список.
Помогите пожалуйста или литературой или кодом

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Вам нужно использовать функцию `fetch` из JavaScript.

Эта функция выполняет получение данных через асинхронный запрос.

Ссылка 1: https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/API/Fetch_API/Using_Fetch
Ссылка 2: https://habrahabr.ru/post/252941/

Пример использования из второй ссылки:

```
fetch('http://some-site.com/cors-enabled/some.json', {mode: 'cors'})  
  .then(function(response) {  
    return response.text();  
  })  
  .then(function(text) {  
    console.log('Request successful', text);  
  })  
  .catch(function(error) {  
    log('Request failed', error)  
  });
```

Далее после получения данных вам надо будет их обработать и преобразовать в список имён посредством JavaScipt.